# error at getting image from url?

Tags: ios, swift3

```
 let defaultConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main
  let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: defaultConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
    if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&sortBy=top&apiKey=47d2ce48babd47b1bc391b426b89ca23")
    {
        (defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil{
                return
            }
            do {
                let resultJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                if var dataDictionary = resultJson {
                    // dataDictionary["access_token"] as AnyObject
                    self.dataArray = dataDictionary["articles"] as! [Any]
                    var dataDictionary22 = self.dataArray[0] as! [String: Any] as [String : AnyObject]
                    let url = URL(string:
                        "\(String(describing: dataDictionary22["urlToImage"]!))")
                     print("url -> \(String(describing: url!))")
                    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
                        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                            return
                        }


                            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)

                    }

                    task.resume()

                }

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }

        }).resume()
    }
```

i am trying to get news updates from open api through nsurlsession and it has dictionary->array->dictionary->at key "urlToImage"
but iam getting url like http://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8968140-1x1-700x700.jpg but not getting image file in data it was empty can any one minimige the code lenth and solve my problem

Comment: Don't use `[String:AnyObject]` as JSON dictionary representation in Swift 3 at all. A JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` because all JSON dictionary values are (Swift) value types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this piece of code, you can parse that specific URL response successfully, I have tested it in a Playground.

This: `"\(String(describing: dataDictionary22["urlToImage"]!))"` is not the way get a `String` from an `AnyObject`, you should use conditional casting.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=abc-news-au&sortBy=top&apiKey=47d2ce48babd47b1bc391b426b89ca23"){
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil, let data = data else {
            print(error!);return
        }
        guard let resultJson = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String:Any] else {
            return
        }
        print(resultJson)
        guard let articles = resultJson["articles"] as? [[String:Any]], let firstArticle = articles.first else { return }
        guard let imageUrlString = firstArticle["urlToImage"] as? String, let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil, let data = data else {
                print(error!);return
            }
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageView.image = image
            }
        }).resume()
    }).resume()
}
```

If you want to get all article pictures (in your question you were only parsing the first one), just change `guard let articles = resultJson["articles"] as? [[String:Any]], let firstArticle = articles.first else { return }` to the following:

```
for article in articles {
    guard let imageUrlString = article["urlToImage"] as? String, let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil, let data = data else {
            print(error!);return
        }
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
        //use the image
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: getting error This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes

Comment: You need to do UI updates from the main thread, check my updated answer

Comment: i want to get articles not first i need dynamically  guard let articles = resultJson["articles"] as? [[String:Any]],let firstArticle = [articles[number]] else { return } . but it showing error

Comment: You were only parsing the first article in your question and displaying that single image, so I assumed that was on purpose. I've updated my answer on how to parse all articles, check it out.